# Add content to start of all requests

Tags: htaccess, html, configuration

In a `.htaccess` file or another server configuration file, is there a way to add content to the start of all requests, for example:

`index.html`

```
World!
```

`.htaccess` or another server configuration file

```
# Fake code
addContent("Hello");
```

And then when you visit `index.html` you will read

```
Hello World
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .htaccess you can add this

```
# Prepend the file
php_value auto_prepend_file "/path/to/header.php"

# Append file to bottom of page
php_value auto_append_file "/path/to/footer.php"
```

If you are the person who has 100% control of the site this may not be a problem, but if others come in later they may tear some hair out trying to work out where the content is coming from